# Spring Security Https - Error when try to login with https

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I want to switch from http to https when user clicks on login/registration page (/user/add) and keep https session till logout.
Homepage is available without https.
My code in security.xml:

```
<http auto-config="true">  
    <intercept-url pattern="/home*" access="ROLE_USER" />  
    <intercept-url pattern="/user/add*" access="ROLE_USER" requires-channel="https"/> 
    <form-login login-page="/user/add" default-target-url="/" authentication-failure-url="/user/add" />

    <port-mappings>
        <port-mapping http="8080" https="8181"/>
    </port-mappings>


</http>
```

I am using Glassfish 4.0, Spring MVC and Spring Security 3.0

When I am clicking on button to page /user/add, I get this Error:

```
ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Have you used some tool to have a look at the real response sended by the server (have had a look at the redirects)? - What was the response?

Comment: no, I simple want to get https session when login

Comment: So use this tool for debugging. If you still have no clue whats going on, AFTER this debugging, then post the obtained response in your question.

Comment: You are saying that to access the login page, you need permission "ROLE_USER" e.g. you have to be logged in. So it redirects the non-logged in user to the login page, which needs to be logged in for, so redirects to login-page.. etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get too many redirects because you set you login page to "/user/add" (of course, it is not a page - you should set this address to a real login page). However, when the user gets to this address he is blocked, because the line before you define "/user/add*" as secured resource that needs to be authenticated. to the authentication fails, and then the user is redirected to "/user/add", because this is defined as the 'authentication-failure-url'.

This is the explanation.

Hope that helps :-)

PS if you want to see an example how to do the thing you want, have a look [here](https://github.com/OhadR/oAuth2-sample/blob/master/oauth2-auth-server/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/spring-servlet.xml#L62) (search for "form-login")

Comment: Thx, now I understand the problem, but I am fresh in Spring and I still don't know how to make it, that after clicking /user/add.html page (there is form for login), it change session to https and keep it till user clics logout. Could you help me?

Comment: @m.aibin - have you made any changes to your config following this advice? If you just add an intercept-url rule for your login page URL that is permitAll and requires-channel = https

Comment: If I used permitAll, I get this:
nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported configuration attributes: [permitAll]

Comment: Actually - you will need to update the <http> element so it includes use-expressions="true" alongside the auto-config attribute if you want to use permitAll